# textarea values are not submitted on enter key

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have tried every possible combination for the textarea to submit the value when enter key is pressed but none of the worked.I cant find the error. plz help.

```
$('.textarea').keyup(function(e){
            if( e.which == 13 ){
                $('#messageFrm').submit();
            }

        });


        $('#messageFrm').submit(function(){

            var message = $('.textarea').val();

            $.post("handlers/messages.php",{msg:message,condition:"sendMessage"}, function(response){

                if( response==1 ){
                    LoadChat();
                    document.getElementById('messageFrm').reset();
                }

            });

            return false;

        });
```

here's my jquery script.
Actually on pressing enter the data is inserted on the database but the textarea still hve the message and a new line is added with enter key.

Comment: it should work. but i dont where i m wrong

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/bys85zcx/1/). Presumably your response **isn't** `== 1` and so `reset` never gets called. So that's what you want to debug. You probably have whitespace or similar in the response.

Comment: Please provide more of your code. Can you post your form markup and the request response from the submit?

Answer (score 1):

After submitting form all you are doing to clear text area then why not just code to clear value of text area directly

For that just replace

```
 document.getElementById('messageFrm').reset();
```

With

```
 $('.textarea').val('');
```

Comment: @max: please accept this answer if you find it helpful to you or let us know what more we can help you with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keydown` of jQuery to add a listener for `textarea` and `event.preventDefault()` to prevent add a new line.

You can see my pen: https://codepen.io/blogk/pen/vaPYwL?editors=1010